# Full & Incremental data load - api

Tags: database, api, etl, azure-application-insights

I am using application insights api to get the events data to a database. However, I see that there is a limit of 500.

My use case is - Dump all the historic data coming from the api to database and then run a job every hour so that new data is only dumped into the database

How do I achieve this?

Currently - The code is consuming the api and storing the data in database(only the 500 rows that is given out of the api)

Problem -

1. A 500 limit in application insights api
2. Unable to get all the historic data from the api
3. Mechanism to setup a incremental load - not known

Any idea on this would be very helpful

Comment: I haven't read about a 500 records limit, but can't you use paging somehow? And how important is the historical data? Incremental load can be done using [continuous export](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/code-sample-export-sql-stream-analytics)

Comment: Hi Peter,  the historical data is very important. I have tried pagination and it does not seem to work. I cant use continous export because I want to store my data in a postgres on aws. I understand that continous export only exports data to a azure storage.

Comment: @rathimittha, peter is right, there is no limitation for 500 records reading from application insights. Can you confirm this or provide a link?

Comment: Ivan , this is the message I get, "@ai.messages": [
        {
            "code": "AddedLimitToQuery",
            "message": "The query was limited to 500 rows"
        }.

Comment: I store the data into database too and 500 rows are loaded

Comment: @rathimittha, could you please share us a demo code? Then we can troubleshoot it more easier.

Comment: Ivan, I am unable to share the demo code. But , you can see it here on this link https://dev.applicationinsights.io/apiexplorer/events?appId=DEMO_APP&apiKey=DEMO_KEY&eventType=requests&$filter=timestamp%20gt%20now()%20sub%20duration%27PT1H%27

Comment: @rathimittha, ok, I know this api doc. And you're exporting data to azure sql database, or somewhere?

Comment: I am exporting the data to a aws rds postgres instance